# Giving role based on role ID

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to give roles based on the ID of the role to users in a guild once they join however, cannot seem to get it to give when I provide the role ID and I can when I provide the role name.

I've tried both

```py
@Nao.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    database = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        database='Nao'
    )
    cursor = database.cursor()
    query = "SELECT role FROM autorole WHERE server = %s"
    values = (member.guild.id,)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for role in result:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Members')
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Which works and

```py
@Nao.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    database = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        database='Nao'
    )
    cursor = database.cursor()
    query = "SELECT role FROM autorole WHERE server = %s"
    values = (member.guild.id,)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for role in result:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=role[0])
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

which does not work and gives me the error;

> await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Your query is probably returning a string instead of an int, try `get(member.guild.roles, id=int(role[0]))`

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.